# Composite Index creation, using WDI database from World Bank

Tags: economics, worldbank

This question might sound vast, however I really need some help finding a composite index which I could calculate using specifically [World Bank's **WDI** database](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/all).

The concept of that index is not really a matter. It could be about anything, such as e.g., environment, finance, ..., as long as its parameters are included in that **WDI** list.

I am trying to find a known composite index like **Green national product**, **Happy Planet Index (HPI)**, **Human Development Index (HDI)**, or even simpler ones if the complex ones cannot be calculated with **WDI** available data.

My indices knowledge is short here, so please if someone knows about an index formula and can locate its parameters in that **WDI** list, do suggest that to me.

Comment: Also, I know I could choose an Index like *(Population density (people per sq. km of land area))* because that is composite too, however I'd like something a bit more complex. Anything but HDI..

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised by the question since each and every one of the indexes you cite (GNP, HDI, HPI) have extensive documentation on their calculations that are generalizable to any global data source whether that be the UN, OECD, World Bank, whatever. Look them up on Wikipedia, find their analogue inputs in the WDI list and plug and chug. It would take only a few minutes of effort on your part.

Comment: For the HDI I can't find those: Mean Years of Schooling Index (MYSI) and Expected Years of Schooling Index (EYSI).

Could you please provide a link to them in case you could locate a good subst.?

Comment: Why not tap into the many other sources of global information beyond the WDI? For instance, Quandl.com integrates data from hundreds of sources like the WDI, WHO, UN, OECD, you name it. It's quite likely you can find acceptable surrogates and proxies for these metrics there.

Comment: Yeah there are lots of data available arround. But I got that kind of restriction there and got to use WDI.

Comment: @Gouz  Guess you're screwed then...sorry.